# How to split the background/facecolor in parts?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I wanna have something similar to the following figures
[image]

How to archive such split?
I tried to set the face color but i cannt there only set a margin for x/y values. My x axis are in date format.
I just want something like the 1/4 green, 1/4 red and the other 2/4 default/no facecolor.
Then in the next plot 2/4 green, 1/4 red, 1/4 default and so on.

but also like the right plot. I also tried axvspan but it seems i have to set some values span and not a % part of the plot to be filled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the x-range into 4 equal parts, the [`axes transform`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) can be used.  As `axvspan` doesn't seem to take the transform into account, explicit rectangles can be created:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range('20200101', periods=50, freq='D')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))
for i, ax_row in enumerate(axs):
    for ax in ax_row:
        ax.set_facecolor('lightblue')
        ax.plot(x, np.random.randn(len(x)).cumsum(), color='navy')
        ax.margins(x=0)  # optionally remove the padding left and right
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((i / 4, 0), 0.25, 1, transform=ax.transAxes, color='lime', alpha=0.3))
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(((i + 1) / 4, 0), 0.25, 1, transform=ax.transAxes, color='crimson', alpha=0.3))

fig.set_facecolor('lightblue')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: coloring a fraction of the background]